# sorting the numbers in queue

Tags: c#, queue

so I have a question on queue. 
I need to build a function that takes a queue and returns it sorted from the smallest to the biggest value.
I wrote a function to find me the smallest number in a queue without changing the queue itself ( checked this one , it works)
and then i wrote this :

```
 static Queue<int> Order(Queue<int> q)
{
    int x;
    Queue<int> help = new Queue<int>();
    while (!q.IsEmpty())
    {
        if (q.Head() == Small(q))
            help.Insert(q.Remove());
        else
        {
            x = q.Remove();
            q.Insert(x);
        }
       Order(q);
    }
    while (!help.IsEmpty())
        q.Insert(help.Remove());
    return (q);
```

}

and I really can't see where I messed because it dosent work.. 
so any suggestion? 
ps : I work on c# 2010 , and sorry for bad English

Comment: mmm .. I  don't really know what version is this. And about how it behaves, if the numbers I put are already in order, nothing happens it just prints it , but when they're not it says " unhandled Exception"

Answer (score 2):

try this edited version: (note that your code is also sort input parameter 'q')

```
static Queue<int> Order(Queue<int> q)
{
    int x;
    Queue<int> help = new Queue<int>();

    while (q.Count > 0)
    {
        if (q.Peek() == q.Min())
            help.Enqueue(q.Dequeue());
        else
        {
            x = q.Dequeue();
            q.Enqueue(x);
        }
        Order(q);
    }
    while (help.Count > 0)
        q.Enqueue(help.Dequeue());
    return (q);
}
```

but you can also use LINQ as follow to get sorted queue:

```
static Queue<int> Order(Queue<int> q)
{
    Queue<int> q2 = new Queue<int>();
    foreach (int i in q.OrderBy(x => x))
        q2.Enqueue(i);
    return q2;
}
```

Comment: I would def go with the LINQ route. There is no advantage I can see to implementing on the fly sorting. It would only make sense if the data was being streamed.

Comment: Well , thanks alot for replying, I think I understod what you did there despite that I didn't learn those functions that you used ( I'm not sure if i'm gonna learn them later cause I'm just starting this..) . I actually thought of a whole another way to do this , I was just so curious why didn't this one work. But, thanks again .